# Are there any modules or built in functions to do error reporting in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, error-reporting

Just wondering if there was any built in way to handle error reporting in Ruby?  PHP does it on its own, Perl and Python you can import modules to use.

Levi

Comment: If you're wanting to debug scripts, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try ruby-debug:
http://www.datanoise.com/articles/2006/7/12/tutorial-on-ruby-debug