# How to debug Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, debugging

I copied the following Ruby code from the Internet and made a few changes but it doesn't work.

What can I do to debug the program by myself?

Comment: Please, check "debug.rb" - a new Ruby debugging tool developed by the Ruby core team.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70104576/12201472

Comment: For a more up-to-date answer that shows how to use `pry-byebug` with `pry` to pause, inspect, continue, and step into and out of the methods, check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254461/5192528) for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4124051/5192528).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Use [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/pry/pry)).

Install via:

```
$ gem install pry
$ pry
```

Then add:

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

into your program.

As of `pry` 0.12.2 however, there are no navigation commands such as `next`, `break`, etc. Some other gems additionally provide this, see for example [`pry-byebug`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903754/895245).

Comment: I also recommend using Pry (definitely a life changer!).. Once installed and required in your program, setting a breakpoint is as easy as writing `binding.pry`. It also comes with colour completion, documentation lookup, and possibility to dynamically edit and reload a method..

Comment: Pry's homepage is available here: http://pryrepl.org/.

Comment: `Pry` / `byebug` are great, but not as your 1st step when debugging.  In most cases, raising an exception with `raise object.inspect` will solve your issue faster than opening up an irb session.   I recommend only using the console debuggers once more simple solutions like raising an exception are unable to solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a way to single-step code with `pry`? I couldn't find how to do it; and that's what I expect of a debugger.

Comment: @jpetazzo yes, by typing 'next'

Comment: In Ruby 2.4, Ruby has Binding#irb that starts a REPL session similar to `binding.pry`. This feature is taken from https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/

Comment: If you're stuck debugging extremely complicated ruby code with lots of state manipulation occurring in different places (think ruby gems or rails code with lots of callbacks...), then I recommend graduating from `pry` / `byebug` over to a full IDE setup like Rubymine.  By running your project's ruby code through Rubymine's IDE, you can set breakpoints and track the state of instance variables visually over time, and see how their state changes line-by-line during code execution.  For difficult bugs its a lifesaver.  (Rubymine is also amazing for code refactorings like renaming ruby classes.)

Answer (score 114):

1. In Ruby:

   ```
   ruby -rdebug myscript.rb
   ```

   then,

   - `b <line>`: put break-point
   - and `n(ext)` or `s(tep)` and `c(ontinue)`
   - `p(uts)` for display

   (like perl debug)
2. In Rails: Launch the server with

   ```
   script/server --debugger
   ```

   and add `debugger` in the code.

Comment: -rdebug is rubbish. And unmaintained. Use Pry (see the other answer).

Comment: @SnowCrash - Why do you say that `-r debug` is rubbish ?

Comment: with -rdebug :no need to change source file in order to debug

Comment: For a new Ruby/Rails application, Pry is the correct answer.  But I spent over an hour trying to find an ancient version of Pry to run on a Rails 2.2 app with a specific version of `facets` in the gem requirements, and was unsuccessful.  For ancient Rails apps `ruby-debug` is a bit nasty but gets the job done.

Answer (score 57):

As banister recommended: use pry!
I can only agree on this.

pry is a much better repl than irb.

You need to add

```
require 'pry'
```

to your source file
and then insert a breakpoint in your source code by adding

```
binding.pry
```

at the place where you want to have a look at the things
(this is like triggering a breakpoint in a classic IDE environment)

Once your program hits the

```
binding.pry
```

line, you'll be thrown right into the pry repl,
with all the context of your program right at hand,
so that you can simply explore everything around, investigate all objects,
change state, and even change code on the fly.

I believe you can not change the code of the method that you are currently in,
so you can sadly not change the next line to be executed.
But good ruby code tends to be single line anyway ;-)

Answer (score 38):

***Debugging by raising exceptions*** is *far easier* than squinting through `print` log statements, and for most bugs, its generally *much faster* than opening up an irb debugger like `pry` or `byebug`.  Those tools should not always be your first step.

---

## Debugging Ruby/Rails Quickly:

### 1. Fast Method:  Raise an `Exception` then and `.inspect` its result

The *fastest* way to debug Ruby (especially Rails) code is to `raise` an exception along the execution path of your code while calling `.inspect` on the method or object (e.g. `foo`):

```
raise foo.inspect
```

In the above code, *`raise`* triggers an *`Exception`* that *halts execution of your code*, and returns an error message that conveniently contains `.inspect` information about the object/method (i.e. `foo`) on the line that you're trying to debug.

This technique is useful for *quickly* examining an object or method (*e.g. is it `nil`?*) and for immediately confirming whether a line of code is even getting executed at all within a given context.

### 2. Fallback: Use a ruby *IRB* debugger like `byebug` or `pry`

Only after you have information about the state of your codes execution flow should you consider moving to a ruby gem irb debugger like `pry` or `byebug` where you can delve more deeply into the state of objects within your execution path.

---

## General Beginner Advice

When you are trying to debug a problem, good advice is to always:  ***Read The !@#$ing Error Message (RTFM)***

That means reading error messages *carefully* and *completely* before acting so that you *understand what it's trying to tell you.*  When you debug, ask the following mental questions, *in this order*, when reading an error message:

1. What ***class*** does the error reference? (i.e. *do I have the correct object class or is my object `nil`?*)
2. What ***method*** does the error reference? (i.e. *is their a type in the method; can I call this method on this type/class of object?*)
3. Finally, using what I can infer from my last two questions, what ***lines of code*** should I investigate? (remember: the last line of code in the stack trace is not necessarily where the problem lies.)

In the stack trace pay particular attention to lines of code that come from your project (e.g. lines starting with `app/...` if you are using Rails). 99% of the time the problem is with your own code.

---

To illustrate why interpreting *in this order* is important...

#### E.g. a Ruby error message that confuses many beginners:

You execute code that at some point executes as such:

```
@foo = Foo.new

...

@foo.bar
```

and you get an error that states:

**`undefined method "bar" for Nil:nilClass`**

Beginners see this error and think the problem is that the method `bar` is *undefined*. **It's not.** In this error the real part that matters is:

`for Nil:nilClass`

**`for Nil:nilClass` means that `@foo` is Nil!**  `@foo` is not a `Foo` instance variable! You have an object that is `Nil`. When you see this error, it's simply ruby trying to tell you that the method `bar` doesn't exist for objects of the class `Nil`. (well duh! since we are trying to use a method for an object of the class `Foo` not `Nil`).

Unfortunately, due to how this error is written (`undefined method "bar" for Nil:nilClass`) its easy to get tricked into thinking this error has to do with `bar` being `undefined`.  When not read carefully this error causes beginners to mistakenly go digging into the details of the `bar` method on `Foo`, entirely missing the part of the error that hints that the object is of the wrong class (in this case: nil).  It's a mistake that's easily avoided by reading error messages in their entirety.

**Summary:**

Always carefully **read the *entire* error message** before beginning any debugging.  That means:  Always check the ***class*** type of an object in an error message *first*, then its ***methods***, *before* you begin sleuthing into any stacktrace or line of code where you think the error may be occurring.  Those 5 seconds can save you 5 hours of frustration.

**tl;dr:** Don't squint at print logs: raise exceptions or use an irb debugger instead.  Avoid rabbit holes by reading errors carefully before debugging.

Comment: While I agree with you that reading print logs is tedious, I think recommending to not use a debugger in the first place is very bad advice. Adding a breakpoint and triggering it is exactly the same effort as raising an exception but it gives you a full view of the current state of the application. If any further questions come up as a result of inspecting the dubious state you can interactively drill down instead of adding yet another exception and restarting the application.

Comment: @PatrickR. In my experience IRB debuggers are not a good first step when you're still trying to drill down into exactly *where* a problem is in your code is. Adding and removing many IRB breakpoints takes more time than adding exceptions, and do not give definite answers about your code's control flow in the way that exceptions can with beginners to weed out bad assumptions. IRB breakpoints are also easy to forget about, causing confusion when requests hang.  If you know *exactly* where a problem is and need to debug its state, then sure, start with an IRB debugger.  But often that's not true.

Comment: Hah! Reading the error messages is helpful for Ruby, but _other_ scripting languages? I can't blame the OP for not even bothering.

Comment: My initial reaction was similar to @PatrickR., but I tried this anyway. In the end, I find this to be bad advice, or maybe in the best light, advice tailored to a different use case than I have. In particular a case where (a) not using Rails and (b) have a wrong result but no errors or exceptions raised, i.e. the code computes a number, it's just the wrong number. Trying to iteratively guess where to make a program that would otherwise execute crash is a strategy, but it's more work since I have to keep restarting and re-running.  Each cycle has its own start-up time that's wasted.

Answer (score 21):

1. Print out the variables whenever possible. (This is called printf debugging) You can do this by running

   ```
   STDERR.puts x.inspect
   ```

   or

   ```
   STDERR.puts "Variable x is #{x.inspect}"
   ```

   If you want to make this easier to type, then you may want to use the [exemplor](http://github.com/quackingduck/exemplor) gem.
2. Turn warnings on. If you're running `ruby` then run it with the `-w` switch (eg `ruby -w script.rb`). If you're running it from irb, and you're using a version of ruby prior to 1.9.2, type `$VERBOSE = true` at the start of your session. If you misspell an instance variable, once warnings are on you'll get

   > warning: instance variable `@valeus` not initialized
3. Understand the concept of a binary chop (the following quote is from [Practices of an Agile Developer](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/pad/practices-of-an-agile-developer))

   > Divide the problem space in half, and see which half contains the problem. Then divide that half in half again, and repeat.
4. If you're successful with a binary chop, you may find that there's a single line that doesn't do what you expect it to do. For example

   ```
   [1, 2, 3].include?([1,2])
   ```

   gives a value of `false`, even though you'd think it'd return `true`. In that case, you may want to look at the documentation. Web sites for documentation include [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/), or [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby). In the latter case, you'd type `include?` next to the magnifying glass near the top right corner, choose the `include?` which has `Array` underneath it (if you don't know what class `[1, 2, 3]` is, type `[1, 2, 3].class` in irb), and you get to [include? (Array)](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F), which describes what it does.

   However, if the documentation doesn't help, you're more likely to get a good answer if you can ask a question on how a specific line isn't doing what it should, rather than why an entire script isn't doing what it should.

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered this gem ( turns Pry into a debugger for MRI Ruby 2.0+ )

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

Install with:

```
gem install pry-byebug
```

then use exactly like `pry`, mark the line you want to break at:

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

Unlike vanilla pry however, this gem has some key GDB-like navigation commands such as `next`, `step` and `break`:

```
break SomeClass#run            # Break at the start of `SomeClass#run`.
break Foo#bar if baz?          # Break at `Foo#bar` only if `baz?`.
break app/models/user.rb:15    # Break at line 15 in user.rb.
break 14                       # Break at line 14 in the current file.
```

Answer (score 7):

To easily debug Ruby shell script, just change its first line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rdebug
```

Then every time when debugger console is shown, you can choose:

- `c` for Continue (to the next Exception, breakpoint or line with: `debugger`),
- `n` for Next line,
- `w`/`where` to Display frame/call stack,
- `l` to Show the current code,
- `cat` to show catchpoints.
- `h` for more Help.

See also: [Debugging with ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html), [Key shortcuts for ruby-debug gem](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rdebug).

---

In case the script just [hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13406370/55075) and you need a backtrace, try using `lldb`/`gdb` like:

```
echo 'call (void)rb_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -nf ruby)
```

and then check your process foreground.

Replace `lldb` with `gdb` if works better. Prefix with `sudo` to debug non-owned process.

Comment: ruby-debug looks pretty dated. The git repo for [ruby-debug](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug) has only one commit for this year - is it still actively maintained?

Comment: It also seems to come packaged with ruby, which is great when you're in a pinch. Great answer!

Answer (score 7):

As of Ruby 2.4.0, it is easier to start an IRB REPL session in the middle of any Ruby program.  Put these lines at the point in the program that you want to debug:

```
require 'irb'
binding.irb
```

You can run Ruby code and print out local variables.  Type Ctrl+D or `quit` to end the REPL and let Ruby program keep running.

You can also use `puts` and `p` to print out values from your program as it is running.

Answer (score 6):

All other answers already give almost everything... Just a little addition.

If you want some more IDE-like debugger (non-CLI) and are not afraid of using Vim as editor, I suggest [Vim Ruby Debugger](https://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger) plugin for it.

Its documentation is pretty straightforward, so follow the link and see. In short, it allows you to set breakpoint at current line in editor, view local variables in nifty window on pause, step over/into — almost all usual debugger features.

For me it was pretty enjoyable to use this vim debugger for debugging a Rails app, although [rich logger abilities](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) of Rails almost eliminates the need for it.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend this video, in order to pick the proper tool at the moment to debug our code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwgF8GcynV0

Personally, I'd highlight two big topics in this video.

- Pry is awesome for debug data, "pry is a data explorer" (sic)
- Debugger seems to be better to debug step by step.

That's my two cents!

Answer (score 6):

*deletes all the things*

Welcome to 2017 ^_^

Okay, so if you're not opposed to trying out a new IDE you can do the following for *free*.

### Quick Instructions

1. Install vscode
2. Install Ruby Dev Kit if you haven't already
3. Install Ruby, ruby-linter, and ruby-rubocop extensions for vscode
4. Manually install whatever gems [rubyide/vscode-ruby specifies](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby#install-ruby-dependencies), if needed
5. Configure your `launch.json` to use `"cwd"` and *and* `"program"` fields using the `{workspaceRoot}` macro
6. Add a field called `"showDebuggerOutput"` and set it to `true`
7. Enable breakpoints everywhere in your Debug preferences as `"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true`

### Detailed Instructions

1. Download [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) aka `vscode`; this is not the same as [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/). It's free, light-weight, and generally positively regarded.
2. Install the Ruby Dev Kit; you should follow the instructions at their repo here: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit
3. Next you can either install extensions via a web browser, or inside the IDE; this is for inside the IDE. If you choose the other, you can go [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode). Navigate to the Extensions part of vscode; you can do this a couple ways, but the most future-proof method will probably be hitting <kbd>F1</kbd>, and typing out <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> until an option called **Extensions: Install Extensions** becomes available. Alternatives are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> and from the top menu bar, `View->Extensions`
4. Next you're going to want the following extensions; these aren't 100% necessary, but I'll let you decide what to keep after you've tinkered some:

   - Ruby; extension author Peng Lv
   - ruby-rubocop; extension author misogi
   - ruby-linter; extension author Cody Hoover
5. Inside your ruby script's directory, we're going to make a directory via command-line called `.vscode` and in there we'll but a file called `launch.json` where we're going to store some config options.

   - `launch.json` contents

`{
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": 
         [
               {
                  "name": "Debug Local File",
                  "type":"Ruby",
                  "request": "launch",
                  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                  "program": "{workspaceRoot}/../script_name.rb",
                  "args": [],
                  "showDebuggerOutput": true
               }
         ]
    }`

6. Follow the instructions from the extension authors for manual gem installations. It's located here for now: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby#install-ruby-dependencies
7. You'll probably want the ability to put breakpoints wherever you like; not having this option enabled can cause confusion. To do this, we'll go to the top menu bar and select `File->Preferences->Settings` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> ) and scroll until you reach the `Debug` section. Expand it and look for a field called `"debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere"` -- select that field and click on the little pencil-looking icon and set it to `true`.

After doing all that fun stuff, you should be able to set breakpoints and debug in a menu similar to this for mid-2017 and a darker theme:[image] with all the fun stuff like your call stack, variable viewer, etc.

The biggest PITA is 1) installing the pre-reqs and 2) Remembering to configure the `.vscode\launch.json` file. Only #2 should add any baggage to future projects, and you can just copy a generic enough config like the one listed above. There's probably a more general config location, but I don't know off the top of my head.

Comment: It's 2018 now,  but unfortunately, you still cannot debug a unit test using the plugins you listed here…  Quite sad.

Comment: @MonsieurDart When I wrote this, it was meant for basic debugging of ruby scripts. I'm not familiar with anything specifically about unit tests. If this answer is incorrect or outdated, please let me know what needs attention and any info that can help speed that process up.

Comment: Hey @kayleeFrye_onDeck! Your response is great, I totally give you that. But, last time I checked Peng Lv's Ruby plugin for VSC, it was not able to set breakpoints inside a unit test (or any other test). It was one of the known limitations of the plugin. I think people need to know this before trying to configure their instance of VSC: it takes time and, for many people, running a tests is the number one way to write and debug code. 

Answer (score 5):

1. You can print your variables out along the way
2. Turn on the `-w` (warnings) flag
3. Use a tool such as [ruby-debug](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/ruby-debug.html)

Comment: I'll add that `irb` is a great starting place. Try using irb with small questionable chunks. I love ruby-debug (ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9+) because it makes it easy to stop the running program, examine variables, drop into irb, then continue running.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), debugging ruby scripts is simple and straightforward.

Suppose you have a Ruby script hello_world.rb

#### 1. Set breakpoints

Set a breakpoint at line 6 as below.

[image]

#### 2. Start debugging

Now you can just start the debugger to run the script:

[image]

[image]

#### 3. Inspect variables, etc.

Then when the execution hits a breakpoint, you'll be able to inspect variables, etc.

[image]

#### Further information for your reference

1. If you would like to [use RubyMine to do remote debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638976/how-can-i-get-ruby-debug-ide-to-work/46920856#46920856), you can do so.
2. If you would like to [use RubyMine to remote debug rails running inside a docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760455/debug-rails-app-inside-docker-use-intellij-rubymine/47081034#47081034), it is also straightforward.

Comment: Do we have a way to debug external libraries in RubyMine?

Answer (score 3):

Well, ruby standard lib has an easy to use gdb-like console debugger:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html
No need to install any extra gems. Rails scripts can be debugged that way too.

e.g.

```
def say(word)
  require 'debug'
  puts word
end
```

Answer (score 2):

printf debugging

There has always been a controversy around debugging techniques,
some people like to debug by print statements,
some other ones like to dig deep with a debugger.

I'd suggest that you try both approaches.

Actually one of the old Unix men recently said,
that printf debugging was a faster way to go for him at some points.

But if you are new at some job and need to understand a big blob of code,
then it's really usefull to step throughout there,
putting some breakpoints here and there,
going along with it how it works.

It should give you some understanding how the code is weaved.

If you are new to some other peoples software,
It might help you to step through there.

You'll quickly find out if they arranged it in a clever way,
or if that's just a bunch of shit.

Comment: this is without a doubt the best answer,,,it depends

Answer (score 1):

The mother of all debugger is plain old print screen. Most of the time, you probably only want to inspect some simple objects, a quick and easy way is like this:

```
@result = fetch_result

p "--------------------------"
p @result
```

This will print out the contents of @result to STDOUT with a line in front for easy identification.

Bonus if you use a autoload / reload capable framework like Rails, you won't even need to restart your app. (Unless the code you are debugging is not reloaded due to framework specific settings)

I find this works for 90% of the use case for me. You can also use ruby-debug, but I find it overkill most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is many debuggers with different features, based on which you make choice. My priorities was satisfied with [pry-moves](https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves) which was:

- quickly comprehensible info on how to use
- intuitive steps (like easy stepping into blocks)
- "stepping back" (pry-moves partially satisfies the need)