# How to debug ruby code?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I run Ubuntu 10.10. I just want to debug a simple script. After spending half a day trying to figure out how that could be done I give up. What the heck am I supposed to do?

I installed `ruby-dev` from the Ubuntu repository
I ran `sudo gem install ruby-debug` and `sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide`

I tried a few different ways to make this work. I tried `require 'ruby-debug'` and then setting `debugger` somewhere in the code. But Ruby won't find `ruby-debug`.
I tried setting up `vim-ruby-debugger`, which will take *ages* to execute `:Rdebugger myScript.rb` and will allow me to set breakpoints, but there doesn't seem to be a way to execute my code using that debugger.
And I tried to use NetBeans which simply crashed every time I set up the project and clicked anything.

So, dear community: There must be a way to debug Ruby. Not Rails. Nothing fancy. Just some CLI script. Please help me or I lose what is left of my sanity.

**Edit:**
the gem exec dir was not in my path. So, at least rdebug seems to work now.

Comment: Related question, though more focused on printf debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug Ruby scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts)

Comment: For a more up-to-date answer that shows how to use `pry-byebug` with `pry` to pause, inspect, continue, and step into and out of the methods, check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70254461/5192528) below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ruby-debug is for 1.8+ and ruby-debug19 is for 1.9+.

ruby-debug is easy to learn and very useful. You can tell the application to run until a certain condition exists, then have it break, making it easy to locate nil values, or other conditions that occur sporadically.

From the command-line use `rdebug appname` and you'll end up at the debugger prompt. If you want to run to line 100 and stop you can enter `c 100` and the debugger will set a temporary break-point, the program will run then stop there if it's in the execution path. Once it stops the temporary break-point will be cleared. If you always want to stop at line 100 you could do `b 100` then `c` and the debugger will set a permanent break-point, continue, then stop when the break-point is reached. You can clear the breakpoints, set conditional ones that occur when certain conditions apply, etc. You can type `n` to step to the next instruction skipping over subroutine calls, or `s` to step into them. There are commands to display contents of variables in various ways, so read through the docs.

From inside rdebug you can drop into an IRB shell with your variables already populated so you can poke at things to see what happens. From inside either you can inspect or set values, helping with what-if adjustments. If you do that from within rdebug you can continue the program with the altered value(s) and see how it behaves.

IRB has its place, and it's great for trying things, but it's not a substitute for the debugger, just as the debugger can do some IRB-ish things, but won't replace it. Both tools are a good combination and beat the heck out of relying on print statements or dumping to a log file.

---

[Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) has emerged as a great combination of IRB and a [debugger](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug), and is well worth investigating.

Comment: Being used to using graphical debuggers, ruby-debug was kind of awkward to use at first but it proved quite practical in the end and certainly found my bug. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Graphical debuggers are pretty, but the functionality they provide has to exist at a lower level, under the graphics otherwise they won't have anything to present. I spend so much time at the command line that I forget about the nice layouts in IDEs. Still, I rely on the command-line debugger to show me what is really hiding in a variable; I have my opinions about what it should be but sometimes the interpreter disagrees with me - and it always wins until I tell it different. :-)

Comment: please checkout [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug), seems to be the norm now.

Comment: I changed the link to pry-byebug. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

[pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is better compared to IRB. The following are grab from its [README](https://github.com/pry/pry).

> Pry is a powerful alternative to the standard IRB shell for Ruby. It is written from scratch to provide a number of advanced features, including:

- Source code browsing (including core C source with the pry-doc gem)
- Documentation browsing
- Live help system
- Open methods in editors (edit-method Class#method)
- Syntax highlighting
- Command shell integration (start editors, run git, and rake from within Pry)
- Gist integration
- Navigation around state (cd, ls and friends)
- Runtime invocation (use Pry as a developer console or debugger)
- Exotic object support (BasicObject instances, IClasses, ...)
- A Powerful and flexible command system
- Ability to view and replay history
- Many convenience commands inspired by IPython, Smalltalk and other advanced REPLs
- A wide-range number of plugins that provide remote sessions, full debugging functionality, and more.

> Pry also aims to be more than an IRB replacement; it is an attempt to bring REPL driven programming to the Ruby language. It is currently not as powerful as tools like SLIME for lisp, but that is the general direction Pry is heading.
>
> Pry is also fairly flexible and allows significant user customization is trivial to set it to read from any object that has a readline method and write to any object that has a puts method - many other aspects of Pry are also configurable making it a good choice for implementing custom shells.

Comment: I agree, I was not having a good time installing ruby-debug for ruby 1.9.3. Pry works out of the box & is very easy to use.

Comment: Mega-upvote here. Very similar to python's pdb.set_trace() - I was looking for something similar. Works out of the box in 1.9.3 as stated by Nosh.

Comment: "pry is better compared to IRB": This was true until [Pry.debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) appeared mid-2012.

Comment: Not sure why people insist on calling `pry` a "debugger" — it has no out-of-the-box support for stepping, continuing, etc.

Answer (score 5):

1. In Ruby:

   ruby -rdebug myscript.rb 
   then,

   - b : put break-point
   - and n(ext) or s(tep) and c(ontinue)
   - p(uts) for display
2. In Rails: Launch the server with

   - script/server --debugger

     and add debugger in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The best debugger I've ever used for Ruby is the one built in to [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org).  You have to install the fast ruby debugger gem from Netbeans (I'm not sure which gem it actually is, but Netbeans prompts you to do it).  I find that it works much better if you switch Netbeans away from the built-in JRuby 1.4 to your system's default Ruby installation.  There's also the `breakpoint` gem that's worth taking a look at, and using the Ruby built-in library `logger` from the start of your development is also helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: Netbeans simply crashed everytime I wanted to run it. If my debugging needs will exceed what ruby-debug has to offer, I will certainly check it out, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use IRB. It is an interactive Ruby shell. When errors occur, it gives a trace with line numbers so that you can tell what part of your code went wrong. You can `load` your source files and run individual methods to see if they are working properly. IRB provides useful output - when you enter some code, it will evaluate the expression and then print the return value using `.inspect`.

Comment: Pry is more efficient that IRB. It allows a lot of more flexible and its community is growing (and interops with IRB's community) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Cheat sheet running

```
  gem install cheat
  cheat rdebug
```

This will show useful commands to use rdebug.

Answer (score 1):

To debug Ruby code, you will need two gems: [pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry) and [pry-byebug](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry-byebug).

Here is a simple Ruby script that adds up two numbers and prints their sum. Notice the `binding.pry` statement at the bottom. This statement adds a breakpoint and tells Ruby to stop execution at that point. At this point, we can examine the current state, step in and out of methods, and exit or continue the execution.

```rb
require "pry"
require "pry-byebug"

class Sandbox
  def add(a, b)
    sum = a + b
    sum
  end
end

puts "Welcome to the Sandbox"

binding.pry

box = Sandbox.new
sum = box.add(3, 4)

puts "Sum = #{sum}"
```

If you were to run this code in the terminal, you’d see the following code. Pry pauses the program, and the terminal is waiting for your input. Notice the arrow next to the line number, which tells you exactly where the control is.

```rb
➜  sandbox (main) ✗ ruby lib/sandbox.rb
Welcome to the Sandbox

From: /../sandbox/lib/sandbox.rb:15 :

    10:
    11: puts "Welcome to the Sandbox"
    12:
    13: binding.pry
    14:
 => 15: box = Sandbox.new
    16: sum = box.add(3, 4)
    17:
    18: puts "Sum = #{sum}"

[1] pry(main)>
```

Type `next` on the terminal to go to the following line.

```rb
[1] pry(main)> next

From: /../sandbox/lib/sandbox.rb:16 :

    11: puts "Welcome to the Sandbox"
    12:
    13: binding.pry
    14:
    15: box = Sandbox.new
 => 16: sum = box.add(3, 4)
    17:
    18: puts "Sum = #{sum}"

[1] pry(main)>
```

Type `step` into the terminal to step inside the add method. Pry will take you inside the `add` method.

```rb
[1] pry(main)> step

From: /../sandbox/lib/sandbox.rb:6 Sandbox#add:

    5: def add(a, b)
 => 6:   sum = a + b
    7:   sum
    8: end
```

During debugging, you can examine the local variables by typing ls in the terminal or simply typing the variable’s name. For example, typing `a` shows the `a` variable’s value.

```rb
[1] pry(#<Sandbox>)> a
=> 3
```

Type `up` to step out of this method, which takes you up a level in the stack. I do this a lot, especially when I find myself in the framework code while debugging.

```rb
[2] pry(#<Sandbox>)> up

From: /Users/akshayk/Dev/ruby/sandbox/lib/sandbox.rb:16 :

    11: puts "Welcome to the Sandbox"
    12:
    13: binding.pry
    14:
    15: box = Sandbox.new
 => 16: sum = box.add(3, 4)
    17:
    18: puts "Sum = #{sum}"
```

To continue the execution until the control hits the next breakpoint, type `continue`. Type `exit` to exit debugging.

If, at any point in time, you’d like to see where you are, type `@` or `whereami`, and pry will show you the current breakpoint. You might find this helpful when you are reading the help (by typing help in the terminal while debugging), or have cleared the terminal and want to see where you were in the execution.

That’s pretty much how you debug Ruby code. Hope that helped.

Source: [How to Debug Ruby Code](https://akshaykhot.com/debugging-rails-using-pry/)

Answer (score 0):

Try default Ruby Debugger either by:

```
ruby -r debug filename[, ...]
```

Or if it's CLI script, just change its first line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -rdebug
```

and the script will stop on each Exception.

Or check the following script sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class Hello
   def initialize( hello )
      @hello = hello
   end
   def hello
      @hello
   end
end

salute = Hello.new( "Hello, Mac!" )
puts salute.hello
```

You can debug it as shown below:

```
# ruby -r debug hello.rb
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

hello.rb:3:class Hello
(rdb:1) v l
  salute => nil
(rdb:1) b 10
Set breakpoint 1 at hello.rb:10
(rdb:1) c
Hello, Mac!
```

Source: [Ruby Debugger](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_debugger.htm)

---

Alternatively use `lldb`/`gdb`. See below the simple example to print script backtrace into foreground:

```
echo 'call (void)rb_backtrace()' | lldb -p $(pgrep -nf ruby)
```

<sup>Replace `lldb` with `gdb` if works better. Prefix with `sudo` to debug non-owned process.</sup>

Comment: What a concept. Using the built-in debugger. Who would have thought. Anyway, it worked for me. Was ruby-debug rolled into the ruby command as this default debugger, or is this something distinct?

Comment: No idea, I'm not even Ruby developer, but I had to debug some code at some point which was unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby debugging has a difficult history, littered with tools that only support a specific minor version of MRI.  Thankfully, for 2.0 and onward, you can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).

Command-line usage is simple: run `byebug <your script>`.  You can also edit your file and drop the `byebug` function call in wherever you want to launch debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of console-based debuggers for ruby with different features, based on which you will make choice.

If you important need - is intuitive navigation (for example next moves line-by-line, stepping into blocks), and quick comprehensible  documentation - this works for me the best:

https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves

---

Other cool feature which I had demand - is to debug from inside of debugger. Like if I stopped in Controller's action:

```
def index
    list = Orders.for_user(current_user) 
=>  binding.pry
end
```

Now I want to understand why `list` is empty? - I can run `debug Orders.for_user(current_user)` and see what happens there

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the following for testing

```
require "debug"; binding.break
```