# Any good IDE for Ruby on windows?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, visual-studio-2015

I began learning Ruby this morning, so please forgive me if my questions sound silly ;=)

I had experience programming C++ with visual studio before, so I want to ask if there are IDEs like VS for ruby. (I noticed that I can write python with VS, but not ruby...)

Also, my friend told me that Eclipse can be used for ruby, but debug is painful, because you can not watch the value of a variable in eclipse.

Since I have thousands of lines of ruby code to read and understand, it will really be helpful if someone recommend me a good IDE to debug with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rubymine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) is the only real IDE I know of (trial for 30 days), but most of the people use a texteditor like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), eventually expanded with addons for the language you program in.
I wouldn't advise Eclipse unless you are allready familiar with it, a lot to configure and slow.

You don't really need an IDE for debuging, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124051/how-to-debug-ruby-code).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried Rubymine, it is good, but it is not free... I found a debugger called byebug from you link and now I'm debugging in command line. Not perfect but it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, all IDEs that supports Ruby are

- Netbeans
- IntelliJ IDEA
- Eclipse
- RubyMine

RubyMine is the best IDE, it supports some great features like refactoring

But I use vim , which is you know beyond the best IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans actually support Ruby but i don't know if it brings more options than Eclipse. Check it out : http://www.netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are already comfortable with Eclipse, you can use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com), it's web dev counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Many ruby developers use a full-featured text editor instead of an "IDE". I would guess using a text editor is more popular among ruby devs than using an IDE.

The difference between text editor and IDE can be somewhat blurry, but generally a text editor has fewer language integration features than an IDE. Although sometimes features approaching what one would expect from an IDE are available. As ruby is not compiled, compilation/packaging features are not generally required from a text editor/IDE.

[SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a popular text editor among rubyists, that runs on Windows as well as OSX and Linux.

There is [at least one ruby debugger plugin for SublimeText](https://github.com/shuky19/sublime_debugger); I have not used it myself.