# How does Ruby chaining work?

Tags: ruby, chaining

Why can you chain this:

```
"Test".upcase.reverse.next.swapcase
```

but not this:

```
x = My_Class.new 
x.a.b.c
```

where

```
class My_Class 

  def a 
    @b = 1 
  end 

  def b
    @b = @b + 2 
  end 

  def c 
    @b = @b -72 
  end

end
```

Comment: The following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts/3955730#3955730 may enable you to work out what's going on in Ruby better.

Comment: oh so you assume I don't run debug? ;)

Comment: Had you tried `x.a` (without `.b.c`) before asking the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `upcase`, `reverse`, `next` and `swapcase` methods all return `String` objects and all those methods are for... you guessed it, `String` objects!

When you call a method (more often than not, like 99.9999% of the time) it returns an object. This object has methods defined on it which can then be called which explains why you can do this:

```
"Test".upcase.reverse.next.swapcase
```

You can even call `reverse` as many times as you like:

```
"Test".reverse.reverse.reverse.reverse.reverse.reverse.reverse.reverse
```

All because it returns the same kind of object, a `String` object!

But you can't do this with your `MyClass`:

```
x = My_Class.new

x.a.b.c
```

For that to work, the `a` method would have to return an object which has the `b` method defined on it. Right now, that seems like only instances of `MyClass` would have that. To get this to work you could make the return value of `a` the object itself, like this:

```
def a
  @b += 2
  self
end
```

Extrapolating this, the `b` method would also need to return `self` as the `c` method is available only on instances of the `MyClass` class. It's not important what `c` returns in this example, because it's the end of the chain. It could return `self`, it could not. Schrödinger's <s>cat</s> method. Nobody knows until we open the box.

Answer (score 6):

As support for other answers, this code:

```
"Test".upcase.reverse.next.swapcase
```

...is almost exactly the same as...

```
a = "Test"
b = a.upcase
c = b.reverse
d = c.next
e = d.swapcase
```

....except that my code above has extra variables left over pointing to the intermediary results, whereas the original leaves no extra references around. If we do this with your code:

```
x = MyClass.new   # x is an instance of MyClass
y = x.a           # y is 1, the last expression in the a method
z = y.b           # Error: Fixnums have no method named 'b'
```

Using Ruby 1.9's `tap` method, we can even make this more explicit:

```
irb> "Test".upcase.tap{|o| p o}.reverse.tap{|o| p o}.next.tap{|o| p o}.swapcase
#=> "TEST"
#=> "TSET"
#=> "TSEU"
=> "tseu"

irb> class MyClass
irb>   def a
irb>     @b = 1
irb>   end
irb>   def b
irb>     @b += 2
irb>   end
irb> end
=> nil

irb(main):011:0> x = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x000001010202e0>

irb> x.a.tap{|o| p o}.b.tap{|o| p o}.c
#=> 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `b' for 1:Fixnum
from (irb):12
from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5):

The last expression in a function is its implicit return value.  You need to return `self` if you want to chain methods like that.

For example, your `a` method is currently returning `1`.  `b` is not a method for numbers.  You'll want to modify it like so:

```
def a 
  @b = 1 
  self
end
```