# Getting an error in my Ruby script

Tags: ruby

```
class Card

  attr_accessor :number, :suit

  def initialize(number, suit)
    @number = number
    @suit = suit
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@number} of #{@suit}"
  end
end
```

I'm assuming this creates a new array correct?
But why the use of the AT symbol? When should I use it and not use it?

```
@stack_of_cards = []

@stack << Card.new("A", "Spades")

puts @stack

# => BlackjackGame.rb:17: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas why this error is firing?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as it says in error: variable `@stack` is not defined (or `nil`).
Did you mean `@stack_of_cards << ..` instead?

Comment: Yeah, that was the error. On a related note, when do I need to use the AT symbol? Because I remove the AT symbol and the script still runs well. Thank you.

Comment: @Sergio It's used to declare global variables (especially often in Rails). In a simple script, there's little reason to use it.

Comment: The @ symbol does NOT declare a global variable. It references an instance variable.

Comment: @Sergio Sorry, I'm stupid, with `@` you denote instance variables of object :)  And with `@@` - instance variables of class (much like `static` in java)

Answer (score 2):

If you had warnings on (`ruby -W2 script_name.rb`), you would have got a warning that `@stack` is not merely nil, but undefined. See [How do I debug Ruby scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts/) for more hints on how to debug.