# Get a value to access a value in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to use an input from `gets` to access a value in a hash.

This code does not work:

```
puts "Which word?"
question = gets
question = question.to_s
puts dic_hash["#{question}"]
```

nor does this:

```
puts "Which word?"
question = gets
question = question.to_s
puts dic_hash[question]
```

but this works:

```
puts "Which word?"
puts dic_hash["zwembad"]
```

How do I get the `gets` input from the user to access a value in a hash?

Comment: `dic_hash[question]` # assuming question is a key that you expect to be present in hash

Comment: @djaszczurowski just updated my post for that.

Comment: What is `dic_hash`?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @djaszczurowski How could that make a difference?

Comment: You probably need `question = gets.chomp`.

Comment: @SagarPandya Baw... I'd say teach them `p question` first.

Comment: @Stefan yeah I agree. Pieter, I hope you're taking note:).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby gets() not returning correct string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889594/ruby-gets-not-returning-correct-string)

Answer (score 3):

You may not be aware of this, but the `gets` result includes the return character you typed to submit the value.

```
result = gets
```

*type "hello"*

```
p result
"hello\n"
```

Change your `gets` to `gets.chomp` to remove the trailing '\n`

```
puts "Which word?"
question = gets.chomp
puts dic_hash[question]
```