# Ruby Beginner Class Question

Tags: ruby, class

I'm trying to learn ruby more in depth before I move on to rails dev, but I'm having some issues learning classes.  I can't seem to understand why the following doesn't work.

```
#point.rb
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(p = [0,0])
   @x = p[0]
   @y = p[1]
  end
end

#shape.rb
require_relative 'point.rb'

class Shape

  attr_accessor :points

  def initialize *the_points
    for p in the_points
      @points.append Point.new(p)
    end
  end

end

s = Shape.new([3,2])

puts s.points
```

When I call the function I get a no method error for NilClass, which I'm assuming is referring to @point.append.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try this:

```
def initialize *the_points
  @points = []
  for p in the_points
    @points << Point.new(p)
  end
end
```

You get NilClass error because @points instance variable is Nil, and NilClass, which does not have append() method.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error: `shape.rb:11:in block in initialize: undefined method 'append' for []:Array (NoMethodError)`

Which is really confusing to me, since I'd think that array would be fine with append.  I'm on ruby 1.9.2 if that matters.

Comment: @tshauck - you can use `push` or `<<` instead, there is no `append` method on Array.

Comment: Hmm... This is a little surprising, but I don't see Array#append in Ruby 1.9.2. You should probably use << (e.g., @points << Point.new(p))

Comment: muchas gracias @rmk and @McStretch

Answer (score 1):

Better than creating an array and populating it in a loop would be to initialize it like so:

```
class Shape
  attr_accessor :points

  def initialize *the_points
    @points = the_points.map{ |p| Point.new(p) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Point-free style FTW: `the_points.map(&Point.method(:new))`. Actually, I had this idea that classes are procedures, namely they are procedures that produce instances. And just like any object which is a procedure in Ruby, they should implement `to_proc`, so that you could write `the_points.map(&Point)`. The monkey patch for that is simple: `class Class; def to_proc; proc(&method(:new)) end end`.

Comment: @Jörg I wish you got rep for comment upvotes, because that's some crazy good thinking you're sharing here. :)

Comment: I think I posted that somewhere. At least I just found it in my StackOverflow snippets directory, but maybe it's for an answer I meant to give but never posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you had warnings on (`ruby -w` or `$VERBOSE = true`), it'd warn you that `@points` didn't exist.

See some other debugging tips in [How do I debug Ruby scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955688/38765)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize @points to be a new array. It starts off as nil.

```
  def initialize *the_points
    @points = [];
    for p in the_points
      @points.append Point.new(p)
    end
  end
```