# Why are the three dots written to a new line?

Tags: ruby, string, format

```
puts "Hello! Reading temperature value from data file..."
num = File.read("temp.dat")
puts "The number is #{num}..."
celsius = num.to_i
fahrenheit = (celsius.to_i * 9 / 5) + 32
puts "The Fahrenheit value is: #{ fahrenheit }."
```

In the third line, the `...` after the `#{num}` block are printed in a new line. I was under the impression that using that block was passing parameter to the display allowing easier formatting.

Why are the dots going to a new line?

Comment: Because the file `temp.dat` contains NewLine character at the end?

Comment: If you're new to debugging Ruby, you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you read in a file, you get the newlines, too. Maybe what you're looking for is this:

```
celsius = File.readlines("temp.dat").first.to_i
puts "The number is #{celsius}..."
```

If you have a look at what you're reading it might make sense:

```
puts num.inspect
# => "20\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Presumably temp.dat ends with a newline character, `num` contains a newline character. To remove the newline character, you can use the `String#chomp` method, which removes any newline character at the end of a string.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the newline is coming in from the file

If that is the case then

```
puts "The number is #{num.strip}..."
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file, you are also reading the carriage return/newline in the file.  Use `String#chomp` to strip off this extra unwanted whitespace:

```rb
num = File.read("temp.dat").chomp
puts "The number is #{num}..."
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to read an integer, the simplest way I know to read a single number from a file is:

```
File.read('temp.dat').to_i
# => 42
```

[`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-to_i) will parse until the first non-digit which would be the "\n". At that point it'll stop reading and will return only the value, converted to an integer.

Doing that lets you clean your code and reduce it to:

```
puts "Hello! Reading temperature value from data file..."
celsius = File.read("temp.dat").to_i
puts "The number is #{ celsius }..."
fahrenheit = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32
puts "The Fahrenheit value is: #{ fahrenheit }."
```

This is NOT how to read a file in general, it's just an answer to this particular question.