# Input does not match the condition

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to get out of a while loop when the input is this:

> BYE
>   BYE
>   BYE

And not this:

> BYE BYE BYE

The code is:

```
my_reply = ((word1 = gets) + (word2 = gets) + (word3 = gets))

while my_reply != ((word1 == 'BYE') and (word2 == 'BYE') and (word3 == 'BYE'))
    puts 'Grandma: ...'
    my_reply = ((word1 = gets) + (word2 = gets) + (word3 = gets))
end

puts 'Grandma: ' + 'Fine, sonny, don\'t hang out with your aging grandmother!'.upcase
```

which is not working. I need help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3955688/38765 has more information on how to debug your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` also returns the line feed and carriage return "\r\n", e.g. "BYE\r\n". This means you  have to strip them out before comparing to other strings. (see [String.strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001189))

```
while [gets, gets, gets].map(&:strip) != ['BYE', 'BYE', 'BYE']
  puts 'Grandma: ...'
end

puts 'Grandma: ' + 'Fine, sonny, don\'t hang out with your aging grandmother!'.upcase
```

Answer (score 0):

The input from  **gets** includes a newline (BYE\n). Do **gets.chomp** to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but may be you are trying to do something like:

```
bye_3 = Array.new(3, "BYE")
until Array.new(3){gets.chomp} == bye_3
  puts "Grandma: ..."
end
puts 'Grandma: ' + 'Fine, sonny, don\'t hang out with your aging grandmother!'.upcase
```

`Array.new(3, "BYE")` is the same as `["BYE", "BYE", "BYE"]`, and `Array.new(3){gets.chomp}` is the same as `[gets.chomp, gets.chomp, gets.chomp]`.