# Why is Ruby concatenating instead of adding 2 values?

Tags: ruby, concatenation, addition

I wrote a small program to test out Textmate 2 (I'm fairly new to Ruby) and it's spitting out that 4 + 9 = 49 instead of 13 for some reason.

```
def add(x,y)
  c = x + y
  return c
end

puts "please enter a value "
a = gets.chomp
puts "please enter another value "
b = gets.chomp

printMe = add(a,b)

puts printMe
```

Comment: Because "4" + "9" is "49" :)

Comment: A good question to ask at this point is, do you understand the difference between strings and numberics? That "4" + "9" = "49" should have instantly triggered understanding of what happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `gets` returns a string:

```
def add(x,y)
  c = x + y
end

puts "please enter a value "
a = gets.to_i
puts "please enter another value "
b = gets.to_i

printMe = add(a,b)

puts printMe
```

Comment: `a = gets.to_i` will do (no chomping).

Answer (score 0):

It's treating the input as string by default I guess, try:

```
def add(x,y)
  (x.to_i + y.to_i)
end
```

Also, no need to return in ruby or place in variable c, it will automagically return the last line of code as output

Comment: It's not as convenient or sense-making as the gets.to_i approach.  When one supplies add("x", "y"), one would then get a result different from "xy", which would be unexpected a weird.  And that's not great for program readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you did `puts printMe.inspect`, you'd be able to see for yourself that it's `"49"`, not `49`, and that `a` and `b` are strings. For more debugging hints, see [How do I debug Ruby scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts)