# Ruby sentinel loop not working as expected (Seven Languages In Seven Weeks)

Tags: ruby, loops, sentinel

Just started working through the Ruby chapter in Mr. Tate's "Seven Language in Seven Weeks".

For the bonus question in Day 1, I am to generate a "random" number, read a user's guess from the input, and compare the guess to my "random" number, then prompt the user to continue guessing with the `begin` loop. However, the loop seems to terminate regardless of what the value of the string the user inputs.

```
# file : day1_bonus.rb
# Seven Languages In Seven Weeks
#
# Guess a random number!

again = "y"

begin
  print "Enter a number between 0 and 9: "
  number = gets.to_i
  randNum = rand(10)

  if number == randNum
    puts 'You guessed correctly!'
  else
    puts 'You guessed incorrectly.'
  end

  print "Play again? (y/n): "
  again = gets
  again.chomp   # remove carriage return
end while again == "y"
```

Output:

```
Enter a number between 0 and 9: 3
You guessed incorrectly.
Play again? (y/n): y
nil
```

Comment: Fair enough question, but here's some tips on how to do debugging in Ruby http://stackoverflow.com/q/3955688/38765

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Thank you, I was wondering how I might go about debugging in the REPL. I will take a look at this.

Comment: Your random number is between 0 and 9.

Comment: @steenslag: zero-based, duh. fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of `chomp`. The regular `chomp` and bang `chomp!`. The difference being: regular returns modified string (and leaves source alone) while the bang version modifies original string in-place.

So, in your code you chomp the carriage return and throw away this work. Either do this

```
again = again.chomp
```

or this

```
again.chomp!
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, I noticed that I need to convert the value of number using `to_i` method. Otherwise it won't work. I will correct it above.