# Ruby hash error: undefined method [] when attempting to set deeply nested keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a piece of code like this:

```
my_hash = {}
first_key = 1
second_key = 2
third_key = 3
my_hash[first_key][second_key][third_key] = 100
```

and the ruby interpreter gave me an error says that:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

So does it mean I cannot use hash like that? or do you think this error might because of something else?

Comment: Hints on how to debug your code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3955688/38765

Comment: Allan, you should probably accept one of the answers, unless you consider that your question wasn't fully answered. (Probably either texasbruce's or mine, since we told you a way to achieve what you want. Though I repeat that it's not necessarily good style.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hashes aren't nested by default. As `my_hash[first_key]` is not set to anything, it is `nil`. And `nil` is not a hash, so trying to access one of its elements fails.

So:

```
my_hash = {}
first_key = 1
second_key = 2
third_key = 3

my_hash[first_key] # nil
my_hash[first_key][second_key]
# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

my_hash[first_key] = {}
my_hash[first_key][second_key] # nil

my_hash[first_key][second_key] = {}

my_hash[first_key][second_key][third_key] = 100
my_hash[first_key][second_key][third_key] # 100
```

Comment: hello thank you, but actually I made my hash to be static (`@@my_hash`), so will the sub hashes be static as well? So the sub_hashes will not be initialized again if I put this piece of code in a loop?

Comment: @AllanJiang There's no such thing as "static" in Ruby.

Answer (score 8):

The way you are using hash is not valid in Ruby, because every single value has to be assigned to a hash first before going to nested hash(I suppose you were from PHP?), but you can use vivified hash:

```
my_hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc)}
first_key = 1
second_key = 2
third_key = 3
my_hash[first_key][second_key][third_key] = 100
p my_hash

#output: {1=>{2=>{3=>100}}}
```

This is the way you might be comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hashes like that; `my_hash[first_key]` is just nil, and then the next indexing operation fails. It's possible to make a hash object that behaves in the way you're looking for -- see http://t-a-w.blogspot.co.uk/2006/07/autovivification-in-ruby.html -- but it's not clear that this is good style.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
class NilClass

  def [] key
    nil
  end

end
```

in the initializers like `nil_overrides.rb` and you will able to use `nil['xxx']`.