# Homebrew formula install step by step for debug

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew

I would like to install a formula step by step, get the folder where the files are extracted from the zip, run configure, and do make and make install with the options set by the formula.

When I run:

```
brew install -vd formula
```

It justs show the output, I would like to stop at each stage.
It is possible ?

Comment: It shows the output **unless something fails**. Then it gives you a menu to ask what you want to do, including use the debugger.

Comment: Nothing fails in my case, but I need to stop to check some parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew will automatically give you a chance to inspect things when something goes wrong in the installation. Therefore, all you have to do to let yourself poke around is to *force* something to go wrong at whatever point you wish. For example, you could include this in your formula:

```
system "false"
```

Homebrew will present a menu asking you want you want to do. Choose the "shell" option to inspect the build environment.

You might also try [running the `brew` command in the Ruby debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955688/33732). Then you can set breakpoints wherever you wish.