# How to use the debugger with Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-2.0

I know the debugger gem is not and never will be compatible with ruby 2.0 per "[officially support ruby 2.X](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/47#issuecomment-44027702)".

In the changelog of Ruby 2.0 is:

> Debug support
>
> DTrace support, which enables run-time diagnosis in
>
> production TracePoint, which is an improved tracing API

Is there something out of the box for debugging with Ruby 2.0? Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The debugger gem can be used but it still has issues.

Install [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) which was written for Ruby 2.0 debugging.

For breakpoints,  use the `byebug` command in your code instead of `debugger`.

Comment: Doesn't actually appear to work with Ruby 2.0.0 (http://stackoverflow.com/q/17044127/388916)

Comment: It works, I use byebug every day : Rails 3.2.13, rvm 1.20.10, ruby 2.0.0p195 and gem byebug 1.4.0.

Comment: @Codemonkey, byebug doesn't (and won't) work with Ruby 1.9.x but it _must_ work for Ruby 2.0.0 because that's its only purpose. I just answered your question, if byebug is still not working for you, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Version 1.4.0 of the debugger gem now installs without problems. There are still some issues but this should be fixed soon.

The debugger gem does not play well with Ruby 2. Instead, install the Byebug gem that is fully compatible with Ruby 2.

Comment: any details on the issues? I'm having trouble with "next" acting like "step", which makes it impossible to use.

Comment: Hi @StevenSoroka, I made this gem to overcome debugger's issues with Ruby 2.0: [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). If you try it and have any issues, please let me know.

Comment: You are welcome @PaulAlexander. It was killing me too...that's why I made it!

Comment: @deivid why release yet another gem instead of fixing the debugger gem? it seems to be the most popular debugger library at the moment.

Comment: @rubii I did try helping, but my help was rejected (see https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/47#issuecomment-14965459). The way things stand now, I'm very happy using byebug regardless of its lack of popularity.

Comment: @deivid i see. maybe i missed it, but i would add some information to the readme about why people should use your fork instead of the debugger gem. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### debug.rb (aka binding.break)

Consider using a new Ruby debugging tool called [debug.rb](https://github.com/ruby/debug).

It supports syntax highlighting and many more out-of-the-box.

Also, it is worth mentioning that it is developed by the Ruby core team.

Just place `binding.break` anywhere in your codebase.

Here is an example:

[image: binding.break example]

Also, it is a [default Rails debugger starting from version 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43187).

**Notes:**

- Do not forget about `require 'debug'`
- `q    # quit command`

**Sources:**

- [debug.rb](https://github.com/ruby/debug)
- [Modify source code with binding.break (similar to binding.pry or binding.irb)](https://github.com/ruby/debug#modify-source-code-with-bindingbreak-similar-to-bindingpry-or-bindingirb)
- [Rails 7 replaced byebug with ruby/debug](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/09/29/rails-7-ruby-debug-replaces-byebug.html)
- [Depend on ruby/debug, replacing Byebug](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43187)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pry](http://pryrepl.org):

```
gem install pry  
gem install pry-debugger
```

See "[Debugging Ruby With Pry](http://knomedia.github.io/blog/2013/01/21/debugging-ruby-with-pry/)".

Comment: Pry is great if I want to print out state or examine things and can know where to hit pry points.  It doesn't allow me to step or next or set breakpoints ahead of times, and as such isn't really an adequate substitution for debuggers when debuggers are available.