# How do I scale the stack when debugging with byebug?

Tags: ruby, minitest, byebug

I'm currently getting an error that looks like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `debug' for nil:NilClass
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/lib/project/misc.rb:23:in `debug'
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/lib/project/validation/google_geocoding_validation_engine.rb:49:in `block in compare_addresses'
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/lib/project/validation/google_geocoding_validation_engine.rb:43:in `each'
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/lib/project/validation/google_geocoding_validation_engine.rb:43:in `compare_addresses'
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/lib/project/validation/google_geocoding_validation_engine.rb:32:in `valid?'
    /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Company/Project/specs/project/validation/google_geocoding_validation_engine_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Validation>'
    /home/tomas/ruby2/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1301:in `run'
```

I figured I'd try using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to figure out why the object is `nil` since it's never supposed to be `nil`. I placed `byebug` just above the erroneous line:

```
def debug(&block)
  if @logger.nil?
    byebug
  end

  @logger.debug(@logger_name, &block)
end
```

And ran the tests. I was dropped to the byebug debugging interface and could confirm that the object was indeed `nil`. The problem is that I can't climb up the stack:

```
(byebug) up
*** Adjusting would put us beyond the oldest (initial) frame.
(byebug) down
*** Adjusting would put us beyond the newest (innermost) frame.
(byebug) backtrace
--> #0  AddressKit::Misc::Logging.debug(block#Proc) at /mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/Kvantel/Address Kit/lib/addresskit/misc.rb:25
Warning: saved frames may be incomplete; compare with caller(0)
```

Why can't I go up the stack? Is this an issue with byebug or perhaps an incompatibility with MiniTest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer for byebug >= 1.5.0

Printing and moving around the callstack in situations like this one should *just work* and the OP wouldn't have this issue.

#### Answer for byebug < 1.5.0 (also applicable to debugger or ruby-debug)

Byebug won't start tracking down callstack information until `Byebug.start` is called, which is internally called by the `byebug` command. So by the time you get the debugging prompt, only one callstack frame has been saved, that's why you get that message:

```
Warning: saved frames may be incomplete; compare with caller(0)
```

and that's why you can't move `up` or `down`: there's only one frame.

To properly navigate the stack, you need to start Byebug higher up, by dropping `Byebug.start` wherever you want to start tracking down callstack info. For example, before line 56 in `google_geocoding_validation_engine_spec.rb`. If you want full stack information, you can run byebug from the outset, by running the byebug executable:

```
byebug rake
```

or however you are running your specs.

If you still have issues, please let me know!

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked, but now I get an error when trying to list the backtrace.  In my case, when byebug tries to describe line #2 of the stack, it fails with the following text: "INTERNAL ERROR!!! no implicit conversion of nil into String". It fails in "byebug/processor.rb:78" in `initialize`. This means that any time I use the `backtrace` command or repeat the `up` command until I reach the specific stack frame, the debugger prints an error and resets to the deepest frame. Pretty annoying. I'm including this information since I got the impression you're a contributor (or the author) of `byebug`.

Comment: Yes, I am. Could you please open an issue [here](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/new)? Hopefully I can reproduce the error myself and fix it. Thanks!