# error in install ruby-debug-base on ruby 2.0.0p247

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am running into the following issue:
   how to install debugger for ruby

```
C:\windows\system32>ruby -v
ruby   (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

C:\windows\system32>gem install ruby-debug-base
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary   
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/linecache
-0.46 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/linecache-0.46/ext/gem_mak
e.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ruby > 1.8.x you have to use another gem apparently (byebug), ref: 
[How to use the debugger with Ruby 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200165/how-to-use-the-debugger-with-ruby-2-0)

Comment: Don’t simply link to another question in your answer, instead vote/flag to close as duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I don't believe I have vote/flagging rights at the time when I wrote it :)