# Debugger cannot compile on Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-2.0

Originally posted here: "[How to use the debugger with Ruby 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200165/how-to-use-the-debugger-with-ruby-2-0/)"

I keep ending up back here, but I have a different problem. I don't have the option to change to Byebug right now. We are currently stuck on "debugger" for now, and I cannot install it.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir
  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include
  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib
  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog
  --srcdir=.
  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/Users/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require': cannot load such file -- debugger/ruby_core_source (LoadError)
  from /Users/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
  from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you change the gem used solely for development?

Comment: what gem are you installing? try byebug

Comment: Using `debugger` for rubies after 2.0 is not a good idea. I don't get why you're stuck on `debugger`. You don't have control over your own development environment?

Comment: I'm stuck on `debugger` because it is a dependency of `pry-debugger` which we rely on heavily for development.

Comment: try `pry-byebug` then

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the debugger with ruby 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200165/how-to-use-the-debugger-with-ruby-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

Update: Now Ruby 2.1+ should using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) instead of debugger.

1. clone the [debugger-ruby_core_source](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger-ruby_core_source) to local folder, e.g. `C:\git\debugger-ruby_core_source`
2. copy `C:\git\debugger-ruby_core_source\lib` to `C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.2`
3. run the `gem install debugger` again.

I'm now sure why the gems debugger-ruby_core_source didn't copy the lib to that folder, but certainly the [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) need it.