# How can I get ruby-debug-ide to work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant, ruby-debug, ruby-debug-ide

I can't get my ruby-debug-ide to work properly. I have a basic rails app, and I would like to debug in RubyMine. Before I even start RubyMine, I need to enable rdebug-ide in my vagrant VM. When I navigate to my project directory, I have read online I need to enter the following command:

```
rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 - bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

However when I run this command, I get this message:
[image]

I have also tried a modified version of the above command: (an extra dash)

```
rdebug-ide --port 1236 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

And I get this as a result:
[image]
This looks good at first, but then the server never starts. It never displays the server info and it just sits here and hangs until I CTRL+C out of the server. I can't get the rdebug-ide to work in conjunction with rails. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: are you using fixed IP from your vagrant configuration ? if not make sure to forward port you're using (1236) so the host can listen on this port

Answer (score 5):

I've got RubyMine remote debugging to work :-)

Before you start, be sure you have debase and rdebug-ide installed:

```
gem list | grep debase    
gem list | grep ruby-debug-ide

sudo gem install debase
sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

## 1. Start Rails server

First of all, you need to start the Rails server:

```
hello_rails$ rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- bin/rails server
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.2.beta10, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234
```

For your reference, my Ruby, Rails and Ubuntu versions are:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.4

$ lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Codename:       xenial
```

As you noticed, the server seems never starting. It just hangs there. This is actually correct. It hangs there, waiting to be connected, from RubyMine for example.

## 2. Remote debug from RubyMine

Now start RubyMine (I'm using RubyMine 2017.2.4), Run -> Debug... -> Edit Configurations...

Click plus sign '+' to add new configuration, and choose Ruby remote debug.

[image]

Fill the form and click the Debug button. Immediately the server does no longer hang there, and the Rails server gets started:

```
hello_rails$ rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- bin/rails server
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.2.beta10, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:1234
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.2-p198), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Finally, you can set breakpoints in RubyMine, and start remote debugging :-)

Comment: I've been searching for this for hours. I don't have it working quite yet but I'm on the right track now. Ubuntu 16.x / Aptana Studio

Comment: Thank you for this, you helped me isolate a longstanding bug in RubyMine where only one Docker container can be debugged at a time (the issue is that we can only override the default ports 1234:1234 and 26166:26168 under the "Ruby remote debug" custom configuration, but not under the "Rails" custom configuration.).  See: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000788390-Multiple-debugger-processes-with-docker-compose

Comment: I'm attempting to get this working on a linux WSL 2 subsystem. It currently hangs in the IDE. So Im attempting to run it without the IDE
When you run rdebug-ide bin/start etc command on its own. Should the app start? i.e. can you do a basic `curl http://localhost:3000`

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions of ruby-debug-ide, you can --skip_wait_for_start when running and it will immediately start the rails server (see https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/pull/167/files)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add the command to the Ruby Remote Debug Configuration inside of RubyMine.

`Run > Edit Configurations > Add Ruby remote debug` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to replace `-- bin/rails` with relative path: `-- ../../../../../usr/local/bin/rails`, because once I pressed `CTRL+c` I saw the message stating `/usr/src/app/bin/rails` was not found.