# Ruby exercise using ARGV

Tags: ruby

I have to create the following pattern:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Using a `ARGV` and this is what I have so far:

```
height = ARGV[0]
output = ""


height.to_i.times do |i|
  output << "*" * i
  output << "\n"
end
puts output
```

But every time I run `ruby pyramid.rb 5` on my mac terminal, I get the following output:

```
$ ruby pyramid.rb 5

*
**
***
****
```

Why is it giving me 4 when it needs to have 5 of them?

Comment: I've edited the output - note the empty line? That's `"*" * 0`, as describe in  [Chris Schmich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32751643/477037)

Answer (score 4):

[`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) yields values from `0` to `n-1`, so you're getting lines of `0` up to `4` stars.

You mentioned this was an exercise, so I'll leave the fix up to you.

In general, to troubleshoot these kinds of problems, it's best to [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955688/how-do-i-debug-ruby-scripts) or add diagnostic printing (e.g. `puts` statements) to trace the values of variables and ensure they're what you expected.

For example, in this case, you could add `puts i` inside your loop to see what the value of `i` is at every iteration. You would see something like `0 1 2 3 4` printed, which isn't what you expected. From there, you can look at your code, documentation, or add more diagnostic output to determine *why* you get those values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation. Yes, its an exercise done from the beginning. Our only instruction was that we needed to use `height = ARGV` and `output = ""` as our variables. Still scratching my head on how to get that final piece that I am missing.

Comment: There are a couple approaches: 1) What would you need to do to `i` in your loop to have it be `1` to `5` instead of `0` to `4` as it is now? or 2) Consider looking at the [upto](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-upto) method and how you could use that here

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but I felt it's better late than never. Chris hinted at the solution. If `i` is starting from zero, you just have to make it so that `i` starts from `1` by simple adding `i += 1`. see example below:

```rb
height = ARGV[0]
output = ""
height.to_i.times do |i|
  i += 1
  output << "*" * i
  output << "\n"
end
puts output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis

The problem in your code is the use of [Integer#times](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-times). Per the documentation, the #times method:

> [i]terates the given block `int` times, passing in values from zero to `int - 1`.

So, here is your given code, with comments:

```
height.to_i.times do |i| # when `height = 5`, equivalent to `(0..4).each`
  output << "*" * i      # will be "" on the first pass when i == 0
  output << "\n"
end
```

### Solution

In this case, you should use the [Integer#upto](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-upto) method instead of Integer#times, with `1` as your starting value. Consider the following example, rewritten as a one-liner you can run from the command prompt:

```
$ ruby -e '1.upto(Integer(ARGV[0])) { |i| puts "*" * i }' 5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

In addition to giving the expected results on standard output, it also does away with string mutation, declaring an *output* variable, and other non-essentials. The use of [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) will also raise an exception if *ARGV[0]* can't be cast as an integer, rather introducing subtle bugs such as when `ARGV[0] == ""`.